# package.json bug with npm init -y install

Tags: node.js, npm, sass

I installed node.js for the sake of sass compiling, i havent touched any of javascript for now so all the documentation I went through to solve this problem is really complicated for me. So when i put **npm init -y** command in VScode terminal it installs package.json file that has a debug property between line 5 and 6.
[image]

when i click on "debug" errors that show into my terminal are these...

```
"Error: no test specified" 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! c@1.0.0 test: `echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the c@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-27T00_42_32_091Z-debug.log
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
PS C:\Users\Desktop\c>
```

**And here is log file**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'test'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v14.11.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'pretest', 'test', 'posttest' ]
5 info lifecycle c@1.0.0~pretest: c@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle c@1.0.0~test: c@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle c@1.0.0~test: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle c@1.0.0~test: PATH: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\\Desktop\c\node_modules\.bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle c@1.0.0~test: CWD: C:\Users\\Desktop\c
10 silly lifecycle c@1.0.0~test: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1' ]
11 silly lifecycle c@1.0.0~test: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle c@1.0.0~test: Failed to exec test script
13 verbose stack Error: c@1.0.0 test: `echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1047:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
14 verbose pkgid c@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\\Desktop\c
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19041
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "test"
18 verbose node v14.11.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.8
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error c@1.0.0 test: `echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the c@1.0.0 test script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VScode is giving you a quick way of running 'npm test', which is running exactly as expected. You can specify commands to run in the "scripts" property. As you can see, there is one for "test", which is outputting exactly what is written there. That is what 'debug' does. You need to hook a real test command there for debug to do anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

That debug stuff is the output for a `npm run test` which you don't care about if you're only installing a package.json so you can install sass for development. If you want to be able to run tests via `npm run test`, change the value of the key/value pair on line 7 to run your tests.

```
  "test": "someTestCommand.exe"
```

But again, if you're only doing this to get sass compiling, you can safely ignore it.